# jquery.click(callmethod)

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('<a/>').click(function(event) { ChangeXYZ(event); });
```

Problem with above is i do not want event but i someother var.

```
$('<a/>').click(function() { ChangeXYZ(var123); });
```

But problem with line is, it is getting value of var123 at runtime and as i am adding this  in loop so always end up using last value of var123. Looks like it is using reference for var123. How can i make it use value of var123 when this  was created instead of click time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use closures

```
function (val) {
    return function() {
         ChangeXYZ(val);
    }
}(var123);
```

note: not tested, but should work.

edit: fixed spelling

Answer (score 2):

Let's say your for-loop looked like this:

```
for (var var123=0; var123<10; var123++) {
    $('<a/>').click(function() { ChangeXYZ(var123); });
}
```

Change this to:

```
for (var var123=0; var123<10; var123++) {
    (function() {
        $('<a/>').click(function() { ChangeXYZ(var123); });
    })();
}
```

Wrapping the for-loop with a closure would do the trick. In fact, if you run your program through JSLint, you'll get a warning saying "Be careful when making functions within a loop. Consider putting the function in a closure."

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you can't put a statement `staticvar123 = var123;` before var123 is modified and change your code to:

```
$('<a/>').click(function() { ChangeXYZ(staticvar123); });
```

Comment: The format mamu used would create the anchor tag rather than just search for anchor tags.

Comment: @Charles I removed that last line not understanding your comment. Should I add it back in?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, have in mind that if you attach a click event inside a loop to the the same element (in your case the element `$('<a/>')`), then you'll end up responding N-times to the same event for that element. So you probably don't want this and you need to move the calling to `.click` out of the loop.

Second, if you still need something like this I believe @sanand0 had a mistake and you should consider passing a parameter to the caller function and using this parameter inside the function:

```
for (var var123=0; var123<10; var123++) {
    (function(v) {
        $('<a/>').click(function() { ChangeXYZ(v); });
    }(var123));
}
```